# 2 finger scrolling not working on ASUS UX305UA

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I've just bought this new laptop and installed ubuntu 14.04 on it, everything is working great except the two finger scrolling... I tried to run this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

And this one:
`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`
But it didn't work. Here is the output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0100:00 04F3:0401                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.227630] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.227918] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.228078] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.229806] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices
[    0.523222] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily`.

Comment: I forgot to say it, but it seems that I already tried this before too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 15.10 you can upgrade to the 4.5.1 kernel to fix the touchpad, it worked for me.
You can get it here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.1-wily/

You will need the following files:

`linux-headers-4.5.1-040501-generic_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.5.1-040501_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_all.deb
linux-image-4.5.1-040501-generic_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_amd64.deb`

Then install them with `sudo dpkg -i linux-*-4.5.1-*.deb`

Answer (score -1):

1) Go to **System Settings>Software & Updates**;
2) On **Ubuntu Software**;
3) Make sure you have everything checked from **Downloadable from the Internet** except **source code**;
4) On the **Other Software** tab check **Canonical Partners** and **Independent**;
5) On **Updates** tab check **Important security updates,Recommended updates** and **Unsupported updates** and uncheck **Pre-released updates**;
6) Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
7) Reboot and tell us if something changed.

Comment: This is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Daniel, I tried this but unfortunately didn't work...  thank you anyway!